# Can I create a checkpoint in IntelliJ

Tags: intellij-idea

Can I do something like create a storage point in IntelliJ where the current code gets saved to say 'Checkpoint 1'. Now I make some changes. At any point of time I can go back to 'Checkpoint 1' and it will restore my files back to the state it was.

Comment: That sounds like you want to use a version control system?

Answer (score 2):

Intellij has something called [local history](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/local-history.html) which let you see the history of changes on your files, you will see different points in time with changes already done, you can compare and revert to that point.

Normally it uses timestamps but you can create labels with a meaningful name so is easier to find the point you're looking for by using
`Select File | Local History | Put Label from the main menu.`

or you can just use Git or any other CSV, you can commit (and push) and later if needed revert or checkout a commit number.